# ошибка в axios запросе (Request failed with status code 400)

Tags: reactjs

Я использую спотифай апи для приложения.
У меня есть 2 компонента, в первом я получаю token из url строки и кидаю его в UseState, и через UseContext передаю во второй компонент, где я этот токен передаю в api запрос в качестве **Headers** ключа, для получения плейлиста треков. Но я получаю ошибку "Request failed with status code 400"

[image: Ошибка]

***1 компонент***

```
const [token, setToken] = useState('') // получаю сюда токен
  const CLIENT_ID = "ffbc598a32f044ab935465bbf1cb48c5"
  const REDIRECT_URI = "http://localhost:3000"
  const AUTH_ENDPOINT = "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize"
  const RESPONSE_TYPE = "token"

  // logout

  useEffect(() => {
    const hash = window.location.hash
    let token = window.localStorage.getItem("token")
    if (!token && hash) {
      token = hash.substring(1).split("&").find(elem => elem.startsWith('access_token')).split('=')[1]
      window.location.hash = 'home'
      window.localStorage.setItem('token', token)
    } 
    setToken(token)
  }, [token])
```

2 компонент

```
const { token, setToken } = React.useContext(AppContext)
    const [imgForTop, setImgForTop] = React.useState([])

    React.useEffect(() => {
        async function getStoreData() {
            const {response} = await axios.request('https://api.spotify.com/v1/browse/featured-playlists', {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
                }
            })
            console.log(response) // ошибка
        }
        getStoreData()
    });
```

Comment: Ошибка 400 это, т.н., плохой запрос. Причину такого ответа нужно искать на сервере. Что-то ему не понравилось. Т.е. это "контролируемая" сервером о шибка.

Comment: Возможно причина этого в том, что в запросе либо недостаточно заголовков, либо они неверные. Попробуйте отправить запрос через Postman, например, чтобы посмотреть какие заголовки нужны